# Find ports a program uses with python

Tags: python, windows, networking, port, pid

I want to find the ports used by 'plugin-container.exe' so I can monitor what IP addresses interact with that program, The problem is there are two 'plugin-container.exe's.
I use Firefox Developer Edition.

I already have the monitoring part down but I need to automate getting the ports some how. From what I've seen, getting them means knowing what PID the process is using, two processes = 2 PIDs. ;_;

I could add BOTH of them but there is a ton of traffic going though my browser and it kills my program when I put all 4 ports in manually.

Right now I'm using this to get the list, re.findall to filter the 'plugin-container.exe' in the list, I then use psutil to find what ports.

I feel like there is an easier way to do all of this.

> import os, sys, win32api, re, psutil
>
> tasklistrl = os.popen("tasklist").readlines()
>
> tasklistr = os.popen("tasklist").read()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
There is another port but they are consecutive.
Meh.

> ```
>    process_name = "plugin-container.exe" 
>     for proc in psutil.process_iter(): 
>         process = psutil.Process(proc.pid)
>         pname = process.name()
>         #print pname
>         if pname == process_name: 
>             print(proc.pid)
>             d = psutil.Process(int(proc.pid))
>             print(d.name())
>             print(d.memory_info())
>             dec = input("Use this one?")
>             if dec in ["yes","y","yep"]:
>                 con = d.connections(kind='udp4')
>                 break
>     for connection in con:
>                 yourmom = connection.laddr[1]
>     port1 = yourmom
>     port2 = port1 + 1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a nice way to find processes by executable name using psutil, then you should use [process_iter](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.process_iter) and [cmdline](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.cmdline):

```
my_processes = [x for x in psutil.process_iter() if os.path.split(x.cmdline()[0])[1] == 'python']
```

(substitute `'python'` with executable name you want)